# I'm trying to get Last month to date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power Bi dashboard tracking several metrics since the beginning of last month . Some of the comparisons I make are **MTD** vs **Last MTD** count of metrics like Total users, No of posts and connections made.

MTD(June) and LMTD(May) were working well last month(June) but when we moved to a new month(july) the numbers are off.

Here's my measure

`MTD_Users = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('reporting profiles'), FILTER('reporting profile', MONTH('reporting profile'[date_created])=MONTH(TODAY())))`

`LMTD_USERS = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('reporting profiles'), FILTER('reporting profile', MONTH('reporting profile'[date_created])=MONTH(TODAY())-1))`

Since July 2nd these measures are not displaying correct figures for MTD(July 1st) and LMTD(June 1st)

Any advice/assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: please update the question title to reflect the problem concisely. it will be helpful for others to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ride off contex filter and that mean we must use function ALL or REMOVEFILTERS;

https://dax.guide/removefilters/
https://dax.guide/all/

```
LMTD_USERS = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('reporting profiles'), FILTER(ALL('reporting profile'[date_created])), MONTH('reporting profile'[date_created])=MONTH(TODAY())-1))
```

Comment: This is giving the total accounts created for the previous month. What I want to achieve is for example get the count from 1st of June to 4th of June if today's date is 5th July.

Comment: then use in filter 'reporting profile'[date_created] >= DATE( YEAR( TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, 1) && 'reporting profile'[date_created] < DATE( YEAR( TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, TODAY())